# Razor Pages Validation Summary ModelOnly Does Not Show Model Errors

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I am trying to use the ModelOnly setting on the validation summary. So it does not repeat the errors for the properties so I can show a Model error from the server (If I set it to `All` it works but shows the repeated property errors)

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
```

However, I cannot get it to show any errors. I am adding a Model error to the ModelState (As shown below) but they do not show up in the summary? I have tried with AND without a key shown below!

```
ModelState.AddModelError("WithAKey", "My Model Error");
ModelState.AddModelError("", "My Model Error");
```

Neither of these work? What have I missed?

Comment: `ModelOnly` option displays the Model level validation error. The Property Model errors are not displayed.So you could not see the property error message in summary.But what you did(`ModelState.AddModelError("", "My Model Error");` ) is correct way to show up in the summary.Please share your code behind.

Comment: @Rena it's a standard code behind. As I say above. If I choose 'All' my custom error messages show. I think ModelOnly is actually broken in .Net 5 Razor Pages.

Comment: Hi @leen3o,Actually I have tested in asp.net core 5.0 razor pages,it worked well for me.That is why i ask you for code behind.And I think you need provide detailed code which could reproduce the issue.